# Struggling to UPDATE value in another table where all field of first table are certain value and first and other table share a field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.
Table 1 has customer info
Table 2 has booking info
Table 1 has CustomerEmail as the primary key and table 2 has CustomerEmail as well.

I'm trying to make an SQL statement to update a Field Value in Table 2 (say P) where all the fields of Table 1 have a certain value and the CustomerEmail of Table 1 is equal to Table 2.

I've not used UPDATE before and am new to using JOIN's.
At the moment I've tried something like this:

```
UPDATE Table 2 SET P='Yes'
LEFT JOIN Table 1 On Table2.CustomerEmail=Table1.CustomerEmail
WHERE Table1.value1='something1'
     AND Table1.value2='something2' up to 14 values etc...
```

Is it to do with the order or am I getting it completely wrong?

Comment: Left join doesn't have to match. Join does have to match. Try using Select until you can match all the data you need to match, and then list out the things you need to update.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ can help to elaborate your problem, as real code can be incredibly helpful and much quicker to evaluate for errors by peers here.

Comment: When I put my code in I got the error of  'near "LEFT" : syntax error'

Comment: I will use sqlfiddle now to try and explain better haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EXISTS() like this:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET P='Yes'
WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from Table1 
             WHERE Table2.CustomerEmail=Table1.CustomerEmail
             AND Table1.value1='something1'
             AND Table1.value2='something2'
             AND....)
```

This will check if a row with the same id and all the columns values exists in table1 , if so it will update the row.

Comment: This has worked! thank you so much, I've been stuck for an hour on this!

Answer (score 0):

I used the exists function commented by sagi and it works fine, thank you!